# Disproving uniform continuity of $x^n$ on [0,1].

Tags: uniform-continuity

There is a proof that shows that $f(x)=x^n$ is not uniformly continuous on $[0,\infty[$ in the following way:

Choose $\epsilon=1$. Set $y=x+\delta/2$. It follows that $|x-y|<\delta$ for all $x,y\in[0,\infty[$.

Now $|x^n+y^n|=|x^n-(x+\delta/2)^n|=(x+\delta/2)^n-x^n\ge(x+\delta/2)x^{n-1}-x=\frac{\delta}{2}x^{n-1}$.

Since I can choose any $x$ let's take $x=2/\delta^{n-1}$ and we have proven that $|x^n-y^n|\ge 1=\epsilon$ and therefore is not uniformly continuous.

I know now that if I choose an any interval, lets say $[0,1]$, then $f$ is uniformly continuous. But I was asking myself if I would believe that $f$ is not uniformly cont. on that interval, why would the proof above would not work?

At the very ending, when I choose my $x$ value, I take not account all values of $\delta$, that since $|x|\le1$, I restrict $\delta$ to $\delta\ge2^{1/(n-1)}$ and therefore me trying to disproof uniform continuity on the interval is not sufficient since I have not proven it for ALL  $\delta$.

Is this conclusion right, or am I completely lost, and if so, why wouldn't this proof work?

Comment: Your second-to-last paragraph correctly points out why the above proof does not work when focusing on the interval $[0,1]$.

Comment: Amazing. I am pretty new to this stuff so I am happy that I understood it correctly. And thanks for taking time.

Comment: $$\left|x^n-(x-\delta/2)^n\right|=x^n-(x-\delta/2)^n,$$ assuming, as usual $\delta>0$ and $x>\delta/2.$ But you switch the signs?

Comment: In any event, the obvious drawback is $x=2/\delta^{n-1}.$ That can be easily outside $[0,1].$ All you’ve shown is that $\delta$ must be less than $1$ when proving uniform continuity on $[0,1]$, which is sort of obvious on $[0,1],$ because $|x-y|\leq 1$ for all $x,y\in [0,1].$

Comment: Yes, you are right, that was an obivous mistake and I corrected it. it should be $y=x+\delta/2$ and then I can switch the signs. Thank you for your comment, you are right - there is nothing useful in that proof, except that I learned something ;)